# conversion from object to char in java

Tags: java, stack

In one of my problem i am getting RuntimeException because there is necessary to convert object to char.I tried to do it by using charValueOf() method to get the primitive value of object but couldn't do it. Here is my code.....

```
while ((stack.size() > 0) && (stack.peek() != '('))
{
    if (ComparePrecedence(stack.peek(), infix[i]))
    {
    }
}
boolean ComparePrecedence(char top, char p_2)
{
}
```

how can i solve the problem? thanks..

Comment: What are stack and infix? What exception do you get?

Comment: more information is needed in order to sufficiently answer this question.

Answer (score 7):

Its generally not a good idea to try to convert a generic object to a char as it doesn't make any sense.  If the object is a Character you can use the following.

```
char ch = o.toString().charAt(0)
```

Comment: if the object is a `Character`, you can cast the object and then invoke [`Character#charValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#charValue%28%29) to get the primitive.

Comment: I suspect the OP doesn't know if it's a `Character` or a String with one character or something else entirely. ;)

Comment: understood, but it would be sad if OP didn't know the type of object his code was handling! :)

Comment: it is exactly i want.@Peter Lawrey

Comment: @mre, This sort of thing happens all the time on SO. ;|

Answer (score 0):

I think you got an exception because you didn't use an instance of character wrapper class. If you use `an instance of the character wrapper class`, then you can call/use charValue method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is caused by the stack you are using.  The stack is Object based, so it allows you to push char types, but when you pop or peek them, they will come out as Object types.  If you are always going to be pushing char type values, you can change your stack code to accept a Generic Type such as `<Character>`.

Another option is to cast the Object back to `(Character)` when you peek or pop by doing:

```
while ((stack.size() > 0) && ((Character) stack.peek() != '('))
{
    if (ComparePrecedence((Character) stack.peek(), infix[i]))
    {
    }
}
```